# store azure function response(function dont have get methos) into json file in pyspark

Tags: azure, api, pyspark, azure-functions

We deployed api in azure function, this api have only "POST" method which dont have  "GET" method,
Now am looking to store the api response in the form of json file in blob location,

If i use below code am getting blank response:

```
url = "<API Path>"
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(url)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read().decode("utf-8")
jsondata = json.loads(json.dumps(data)
```

Please suggets me how can i save the response

Comment: no not resolved

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you have specified POST while calling your endpoint.

```
url = "<API Path>"
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(url)
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
requestData = {'text': 'This is test data'} #if your url accepts any data
json_data = json.dumps(requestData)

conn.request('POST', '/yourmethod', json_data, headers)

response = conn.getresponse()
jsondata = response. Read().decode()
```